# In R, how do I set the specific location of an axis label?

Tags: r

I manually added in some tick marks, but these tick marks are too close and thus overlap with numbers already there. I can specify the exact location for these number labels? Here is an example picture of my problem. I tried changing the size, but there is still overlap.

[image]

Comment: Looks like something that might have started life as an example in package-survival. (That would make this a base-graphics problem). Post some code and data and we can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mtext` function to manually add text on the margins. The `line` and `at` arguments give the position of the text.  See `?mtext` for more details.

```
plot(x=1:4, y=1:4)
abline(h=c(2.6,3.4))
mtext(c(2.6, 3.4), side=2, line=0, at=c(2.6, 3.4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
x=1:10
y=10:1
```

use the xaxt= 'n' to rid yourself of the wrong axis

```
plot(x,y,xaxt='n')
```

then use the axis function to get them exactly where you want

```
l1=1:10
at1=1:10
axis(1, labels=l1,at=1:10)
```

now add a new tick mark somewhere, take out a tick mark if you want.

```
l2=c(l1[-3],3.14)
at2=c(at1[-3],pi)
plot(x,y,xaxt='n')
axis(1, labels=l2,at=at2)
```